# Buddha teaching regarding eating

Tags: reference-request, death

Some one please tell me the story of Buddha said to some one how one should eat as if they are eating their own child having lost in a desert

Answer (score 5):

It's in Puttanmansa Sutta.

> "And how is physical food to be regarded? Suppose a couple, husband &
>   wife, taking meager provisions, were to travel through a desert. With
>   them would be their only baby son, dear & appealing. Then the meager
>   provisions of the couple going through the desert would be used up &
>   depleted while there was still a stretch of the desert yet to be
>   crossed. The thought would occur to them, 'Our meager provisions are
>   used up & depleted while there is still a stretch of this desert yet
>   to be crossed. What if we were to kill this only baby son of ours,
>   dear & appealing, and make dried meat & jerky. That way — chewing on
>   the flesh of our son — at least the two of us would make it through
>   this desert. Otherwise, all three of us would perish.' So they would
>   kill their only baby son, loved & endearing, and make dried meat &
>   jerky. Chewing on the flesh of their son, they would make it through
>   the desert. While eating the flesh of their only son, they would beat
>   their breasts, [crying,] 'Where have you gone, our only baby son?
>   Where have you gone, our only baby son?' Now what do you think, monks:
>   Would that couple eat that food playfully or for intoxication, or for
>   putting on bulk, or for beautification?"
>   "No, lord."
>
> "Wouldn't they eat that food simply for the sake of making it through
>   that desert?"
>
> "Yes, lord."
>
> "In the same way, I tell you, is the nutriment of physical food to be
>   regarded. When physical food is comprehended, passion for the five
>   strings of sensuality is comprehended. When passion for the five
>   strings of sensuality is comprehended, there is no fetter bound by
>   which a disciple of the noble ones would come back again to this
>   world.
>     [SN 12.63](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.063.than.html)